# BTC confirmed however funds not received

Tags: transactions

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with my problem. I recently sold some coins to an exchange and then wish to have few bitcoins i.e. 0.01627139, transferred to my wallet which never happened. Transaction Id given to me by exchange is -  13e049ecf32a3226f7c82b558d968c255971272024a37b3509bb90effa92f8f2.

when I search with above-mentioned transaction id in blockchain.info I see around 120 confirmations to the block however I have not received my amount i.e. 0.01627139 in my wallet and it says as "Unspent". I wish to know is it the fault of the exchange or my wallet provider not reflecting this transaction ? If it is the fault of exchange do i need to ask them to rebroadcast my transaction again. 
What is the "Unspent".
[image: Blockchain information]

Comment: Which wallet software are you using? If bitcoin core, is it fully sync‘d?

Comment: "Unspent" means that the output this transaction created hasn't been used as an input to create another transaction, yet. (So that would be expected.) Have you checked that the address is the one that you expected to receive the funds on?

Comment: I am using zebpay wallet which is same version as installed. I have checked the address it is correct. I still could not understand "unspent" meaning. I will appreciate if you tell me in more simplified way.  Is if fault at receiving end or from the exchange. ? Should i wait or what needs to be done in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait within 1 working day when you sell bitcoins on Zebpay.
After Zebpay gets everything clear up, your wallet will show you the amount of Bitcoin, which is 0.01627139 btc in this case. [Here](https://zebpay.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210116345-How-fast-will-I-get-the-money-when-I-sell-) is the FAQ from Zebpay.

---

Zepbay is online wallet service which means even if you see confirmations on blockchain.info, your online wallet might not show you the exact same transaction history because of some reasons that the company has to deal with. But I am pretty sure your wallet will show you the amount of BTC you see on blockchain.info within 1 working day unless the company gets bankrupt.

---

If there are confirmations then the transaction is confirmed but, it is best to wait for 6 confirmations. Unspent means that there is no additional transaction yet created to spend the bitcoins.

Comment: Selling can take place only once i have the desired bitcoins. First it is not being reflected. If you see the image the block is confirmed which consists 2 transaction. My is not confirmed from it.

Comment: Zepbay is online wallet service which means even if you see confirmations on blockchain.info, your online wallet might not show you the exact same transaction history because of some reasons that the company has to deal with. But I am pretty sure your wallet will show you the amount of BTC you see on blockchain.info within 1 working day unless the company gets bankrupt.

Comment: Hi Yuya, I was going through your response to my comment wherein you stated that company has to deal with it. What is that company has to deal with ? I have received my funds however would like to know how "unspent" becomes confirmed. Do the company does it manually in block chain ? I am now stuck with POSW unspent with coinomi wallet.

Comment: @adikhanna If there are confirmations then the transaction is confirmed but, it is best to wait for 6 confirmations. Unspent means that there is no additional transaction yet created to spend the bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

Unspent there means the recipient hasn't spent those coins yet. If you are the recipient then that means you haven't spent the coins yet. They are in your possession as far as the public blockchain data goes which doesn't mean much in itself since, as you say, your wallet provider hasn't given you access to the funds yet.

This transaction has confirmed so the fault lies with your wallet provider. I suggest using a software wallet like electrum on your own device instead of trusting this online wallet provider.